# Getting int value of Resource from Application Class

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I'm setting up a notification class that needs to be independent of any Activity, but called through my main Application class. I'm having trouble accessing resources.

The Application class gets its context via `context.getApplicationContext()`, and this is passed to the constructor of my notification class:

```
NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationService(context, notifications);
```

I need to set the small icon from my Drawables, and when I add the `R.drawable.tv_logo_notext_bw` resource, the compiler cannot locate it:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tv_logo_notext_bw);
```

Obviously, it needs a context, but the context was passed to the constructor of both my notification class and the `NotificationCompatBuilder` class, so I don't understand why the compiler cannot see the drawable.

Am I missing some crucial step?

Comment: maybe you have the wrong import for R

Comment: No - valid... my.package.name.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource Id's are public static filed and being auto-generated by your Gradle & IDE, this means you should be able to call the from any part of you project,
your code looks fine.

**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (Android Studio)**

1. Try to rebuild your project **Build | Rebuild** 
 
2. Also try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: This error was a canary in a coal mine - it seems that the context wasn't being referenced properly in the Application class... and this error wasn't showing up until I started running periodic tasks.

Comment: Glad for you! Invalidate Caches/Restart is a very powerful tool in any wired problems.